# how can I run two function in for loop step by step?

Tags: python, for-loop

```
fruits=["apple","banana","melon"]
for fruit in fruits:
    print fruit #print1
    print len(fruit) #print2
```

I know output of this script will be like below

```
apple
5
banana
6
melon
5
```

but I want to run this script like
 #print1 > #print1 > #print1 > #print2 > #print2 > #print2

so the output will be like

```
apple
banana
melon
5
6
5
```

Is there any good way for this?
(point is that I want to use for function one time)
(Sorry for bad expanation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to iterate the loop twice:

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "melon"]

for _ in range(2):
    for fruit in fruits:
        print fruit
```

which gives:

```
apple
banana
melon
apple
banana
melon
```

This avoids duplicating the list object, avoids duplicating code, and scales easily.

**Edit:** to iterate over two different functions, separately, you can just iterate over the list twice:

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "melon"]

for fruit in fruits:
    print fruit
for fruit in fruits:
    print len(fruit)
```

For more complex situations you could also make a list of your functions and iterate through those:

```
def print_name(item):
    print(string)

def print_name_length(item):
    print(len(item))

fruits = ["apple", "banana", "melon"]

for func in (print_name, print_name_length):
    for fruit in fruits: 
        func(fruit)
```

Comment: thanks ! but what if two functions in the loop are different? is there any other way?

Comment: No problem. See the edit for how to call two different functions.

Comment: Thank you so much !! I thought there must be a way using only one for loop but I think there is no way like that!!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list of functions you want to call and loop over them first, and then loop over `fruits`:

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "melon"]

for func in [lambda x: x, len]:
    for fruit in fruits:
        print(func(fruit))
```

**Output**

```
apple
banana
melon
5
6
5
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could just loop through the same list twice to achieve the desired logging:

```
for i in range(2):
    for fruit in fruits:
        print(fruit)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use generator expressions:

```
fruits=["apple","banana","melon"]

def getfruits(fruits):
    for f in fruits:
        print(f)
        yield str(len(f)) + '\n'

print(*list(getfruits(fruits)))
```

Output:

```
apple
banana
melon
5
6
5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fruits=["apple","banana","melon"]

for lists in (fruits, (len(fruit) for fruit in fruits)):
    for each_list in lists:
        print(each_list)
```

I make a loop iterating over two lists; fruits and a list containing the lengths of the fruit in fruits.

Then I print out each list.

This could probably be more memory efficient, but this makes the most sense to me. I was going for readability.

Answer (score -1):

You can just run the same loop twice.

```
fruits = ["apple","banana","melon"]
for f in fruits:
  print f
for f in fruits:
  print f
```

Which will get you the result. It may be ugly but it gets the job done.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to do this in one loop.  Is there any reason why this would not work:

```
for fruit in fruits:
    print fruit #print1
for fruit in fruits:
    print fruit #print2
```